# Mod_Rewrite showing forbidden with FollowSymLinks Option

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a mod_rewrite script.

Here's my `.htaccess` file thus far:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/comingsoon.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /comingsoon.php
```

Sadly it is causing an error message. The exact message is:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /comingsoon.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The file `comingsoon.php` definitely exists and can be visited when there is no `.htaccess` files in place.

However, when I remove the `Options FollowSymLinks` line, it all works fine.

What causes this and how can I resolve it so that the option is active?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you're on linux or some *nix with the `find` command, what does running `find /path/to/your/document/root -type l` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was coming up with the server error due to `Options FollowSymLinks` being enabled.